# How configure a mouse key to work as a super key

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, xbindkeys

The super key (windows key) is very useful, it displays all opened windows and It makes easy and fast to move between them. I want to configure one of mouse's buttons to work as a super, but it doesn't works. I am using [xbindkeys](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/11/how-to-bind-mouse-buttons-to-keyboard.html) that grab keys and mouse buttons, it works for other keys but not for super. Xev doesn't show super key. What can I do?.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Bind your mouse key to Alt+F1 or Win+S, which also open the activities overview.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I binded one of the buttons to Alt+F1, it works one time, but no more, what happened?

Comment: Try `b:x+Release` x is a number of the button.

Comment: Thank you so much! It Works!

Comment: The full solution is (x is the number of the button on mouse) : "xdotool key 'Alt_L+F1' " b: x+Release